# AS3 Grammar: Most accurate

Tags: actionscript-3, antlr, grammar, bnf, ebnf

I'm looking for an accurate AS3 grammar (format in not an issue, but I presume ANTLR will feature the most) to use for a practice grammar I'm making.

What is the most accurate grammar available for AS3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this one is pretty accurate if you are looking for an ANTLR grammar: [AS3.g](http://svn.badgers-in-foil.co.uk/metaas/trunk/src/main/antlr/org/asdt/core/internal/antlr/AS3.g)

This grammar has been originally developed a couple of years ago by Martin Schnable and then extended for the Meta-AS project. There are of course other ActionScript 3 parsers available as well, but they do not use ANTLR or another compiler-compiler.

So this is probably your best choice :)

Comment: You can use https://code.google.com/p/as3-commons/source/browse/trunk/as3-commons-asblocks/src/main/actionscript/org/as3commons/asblocks/parser/antlr/as3/AS3.g?spec=svn1284&r=1284 but only as long as Google Code stays online. Couldn't find a GitHub mirror.